# What are some good sources for tutorials on structure from motion using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: opencv, numerical-methods, point-clouds, structure-from-motion

I am working on a project for my thesis, and it requires implementation of the structure from motion technique to create point cloud models of . However, is it possible to define the point cloud model numerically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [SLAM](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-412j-cognitive-robotics-spring-2005/projects/1aslam_blas_repo.pdf) and [PTAM](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/03/06/implementing-ptam-stereo-tracking-and-pose-estimation-for-ar-with-opencv-w-code/) algorithms are what you need. Thanks to them you'll be able to generate point cloud and reconstruct seen environment by moving your camera.